# difference between concurrent user vs active Thread in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Please explain the difference between concurrent user vs active Thread. Is both are same or have any differences in both.

Comment: see https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/7902/what-is-the-concurrent-users-in-load-testing-using-jmeter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JMeter world a thread is a virtual user so ideally the number of active threads should be equal to the number of concurrent users.

Just keep in mind that you need to **properly** simulate the real user by the virtual user to wit:

1. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to represent browser cookies
2. Configure [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) to download embedded resources and use concurrent pool of 6 threads for doing this

   [image]
3. Add [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) to simulate browser's cache
4. Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to simulate the browser's headers
5. Add [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) to simulate "think times" (real users need some time to think between operations, type something into inputs, read text, etc.)

More information: [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)